# vue.js running in kubernetes: Unable to load css and js resources. Getting 404

Tags: javascript, vue.js, kubernetes, nginx

We're trying to get our vue.js working on kubernetes (running in a container using nginx). We use ingress to route to the site, here is our configuration:

Dockerfile:

```
# build stage
FROM public.ecr.aws/docker/library/node:19 as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./ .
RUN npm run build


FROM public.ecr.aws/nginx/nginx:1.24 as production-stage
RUN mkdir /app
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /app
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

nginx:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  _;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/vue-access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/ve-error.log;
    
    location / {
      root   /app;
      index  index.html;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: -ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - backend:
                service:
                    name: vue-portal-service
                    port:
                      number: 80            
            path: /
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```

When i open the page, the index.html is loading, but the css and js are not loaded (404).
I cant understand where the problem is, as when I am running docker image on my localhost everything works fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the root cause. In ingress instead of

```
  - backend:
        service:
            name: vue-portal-service
            port:
              number: 80            
    path: /
    pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```

I have put /* in path:

```
  - backend:
        service:
            name: vue-portal-service
            port:
              number: 80            
    path: /*
    pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```

And everything start to work as expected.